# In SQL coding can DEFERRABLE be used in TRIGGER ? How does DEFERRABLE work?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Can the DEFERRABLE be used in a trigger ?

And how does the concept of DEFERRABLE works ?

It's during the whole transaction then it checks the constraint at the end of all the operations ?

Comment: It seems this is a zombie question that can't be closed as Unclear due to the open bounty, but can't be answered due to the lack of information. Flagged for moderator. http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you mean PostgresSql. The concept of a `DEFERRABLE CONSTRAINT` is one which may be temporarily invalidated during the course of a transaction (with the [SET CONSTRAINTS ... DEFERRED;](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set-constraints.html) command), but the constraints must again be valid by the time the transaction is committed.

For example, below, there is a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint enforcing referential integrity from `Table2.Table1ID` to `Table1.ID`:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  Table1ID INT NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_Table1 FOREIGN KEY(Table1ID) REFERENCES Table1(ID) DEFERRABLE
);
```

Normally, the below insert would fail, if there is no row with `Table1.ID = 2`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(ID, Table1Id, Name) VALUES (2, 2, 'Foreign Key Violation');
```

However, because the CONSTRAINT is defined as `DEFERRABLE` (and we've allowed deferred constraints in the transaction, below), it means we may temporarily violate the constraint, provided that the constraint is met by the time the transaction is committed. In the example below, we address the foreign key violation by inserting an additional row into table 1 to pacify the referential integrity constraint.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
INSERT INTO Table2(ID, Table1Id, Name) VALUES (2, 2, 'Foreign Key Violation Allowed');
INSERT INTO Table1(ID, Name) VALUES (2, 'Fix the Violation');
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

[SqlFiddle of a DEFERRED RI insert here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/66bb1)

With regards to Triggers, `DEFERRED` can only be used with [CONSTRAINT TRIGGERS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html), but the same principal above applies.

Comment: Oracle also supports deferred constraints not inly Postgres

Comment: Yup - OP didn't tag any RDBMS originally, then stated PostGres although contradicted by mentioning SqlPlus. Although tags have been changed, OP hasn't clarified, So I guess we are all still none the wiser :(

Comment: The behaviour of deferrable constraints is pretty much the same between Oracle and Postgres (not PostGres btw)